# Sistema de pesquisa PHP sem MySQL

Tags: php

Eu tenho um site com vários arquivos HTML, e pretendo fazer um sistema de busca em PHP, que me procure por palavras nesses arquivos HTML, e que me mostre a página ou as páginsa em que elas se encontrem mas sem usar MySQL.

Como posso fazê-lo?

Comment: Não estou com tempo de escrever uma resposta, mas uma ideia inicial seria listar todos os arquivos .html de determinada pasta, e então percorrer cada um deles usando `strpos` pela sua busca.

Comment: com `file_get_contents` + `stripos` (ou preg_match) é possível fazer, porem *provavelmente* o desempenho será "bem ruim", para isto você deverá indexar as pesquisas ou os arquivos e neste caso será necessário um estrutura de banco de dados, não precisa ser sql, pode ser um ficheiro que trabalha por linhas, não posto uma resposta pois é um pouco demorado de montar tal sistema, mas este é o caminho.

Answer (score 2):

"Em PHP" é o problema maior aqui, a meu ver.

Se o site usa somente arquivos HTML, pode até ser razoavelmente simples, mas independente de como você faça você provavelmente vai ter problemas com tags HTML sendo indexadas para a busca, sem contar na velocidade da busca e n outras questões. Sistema de busca é um negócio bastante complicado e tem muitas "nuances" a serem consideradas.

Algumas questões relevantes pro seu caso específico:

1. Isso precisa rodar em Linux ou em Windows?
2. Esses arquivos são 100% estáticos ou possuem conteúdo gerado por PHP?
3. Caso sejam estáticos, quão comum é alterar esses arquivos?

Minha sugestão é bem simples:
Faça uma caixa de busca que usa o Google, usando `"site:minha.url.com ".$search_params` para ter os melhores resultados mais rápido.

Se você precisar fazer esse buscador do zero ou tiver outras exigênncias, desenvolva melhor o objetivo que você quer atingir e o porquê, para podermos nos aprofundar no assunto.

Comment: Ele deixou claro na pergunta que são arquivos html, então provavelmente são `.html`, em outras palavras, estáticos. Se é Windows ou like-unix sinceramente não vejo por que levar isto em consideração se estamos geralmente usando as APIs do PHP.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, ele disse que tem vários "arquivos HTML", e eu posso usar `.html` na extensão, chamar de html, e rodar PHP, Ruby, LISP ou o diabo no arquivo se eu quiser. A questão era se havia dinamicidade de conteúdo. Sobre ser Windows ou Unix, é porque uma das características do PHP são as funções `exec()`, `shell_exec()` e similares, que permitem aproveitar APIs do sistema, e que são uma ótima opção se você precisar percorrer um número razoável de arquivos com performance mais próxima à nativa, rodando a partir de uma linguagem interpretada.

Comment: ok, parece legal.

Answer (score 2):

Essencialmente, o que pretendes é usar PHP para localizar uma string dentro de ficheiros.

Duas opções, cada uma mais adequada para a versão de PHP que estejas a utilizar:

## PHP > 5.0

Fazendo uso da classe [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), podemos percorrer uma pasta cheia de ficheiros e um a um localizar a string pretendida:

```php
// Palavra a localizar
$string = 'bubu';

// Iterar caminho para a pasta que contém os ficheiros
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('minhaPastaCheiaDeFicheirosHTML');

// Por cada ficheiro
foreach ($dir as $file) {

    // Ler conteúdo do ficheiro para variável
    $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());

    // Ver se encontramos a string para fazer algo
    if (strpos($content, $string) !== false) {

        // Ena, encontrei, e agora?
        echo $file->getPathname();
    }
}
```

## PHP >4.3.0

Para versões mais antigas, podemos fazer uso da função [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), um pouco mais lenta que a solução em cima, mas perfeitamente eficaz:

```php
// Palavra a localizar
$string = 'bubu';

// Caminho para a pasta que contém os ficheiros
$dir = 'minhaPastaCheiaDeFicheirosHTML';

// Por cada ficheiro localizado
foreach (glob($dir."/*") as $file) {

    // Ler conteúdo do ficheiro para variável
    $content = file_get_contents($dir."/".$file);

    // Ver se encontramos a string para fazer algo
    if (strpos($content, $string) !== false) {

        // Ena, encontrei, e agora?
        echo $dir."/".$file;
    }
}
```